# Не удаляет все нужные строки из TStringGrid Delphi11

Tags: delphi, stringgrid

Работает но удаляет не все что нужно. Необходимо удалить записи старше 2х лет. Дата указана в MaskEdit.
Процедура удаления:

```
    var i,j:integer;
    begin
      with SG do
      begin
        if ARow=RowCount-1 then
        RowCount:=RowCount-1
        else begin
          for i := ARow+1 to RowCount-1 do
            for j := 0 to ColCOunt-1 do
              Cells[j,i-1]:=Cells[j,i];
            RowCount:=RowCount-1;
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

Проверка условия:

```
procedure TForm2.N21Click(Sender: TObject);
//удалить записи старше 2-х лет
var x:string;
ARow,n,The_J:integer;
begin
The_J:=1;
n:=Stringgrid1.RowCount;
while The_J<n do
  begin
  n:=Stringgrid1.RowCount;
  x:=copy(Stringgrid1.Cells[4,The_J],7,2);
  if strtoint(x)<21 then
    begin
       DeleteRow(Stringgrid1,The_J);
    end;
  The_J:=The_J+1;
  end;
end;
```

До выполнения:
[image: До выполнения кода]
После:
[image: После выполнения кода]
Еще раз после:
[image: Конечное]

Comment: а вы не пробовали называть вещи своими именами? Например не `TForm2` а `TClientsForm`, не `StringGrid1` а `UsersGrid`, не `N21` а `DeleteBtn`, вам не кажется, что так ваш код будет на порядок понятнее?

Comment: `try { sg.disableControls();` потом вот это вот все и затем `finally sg.enableControls();}`

Comment: @teran спасибо за советы! Это лаба была прост, за 2 часа нужно было сделать тут уже названия не мешают хд. Извиняюсь что не разъяснила.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//количество строк меняется во время выполнения цикла, нельзя снять значение до начала и использовать, нужно проверять текущее значение а не значение на момент старта
while The_J<Stringgrid1.RowCount do
....
  if strtoint(x)<21 then
    DeleteRow(Stringgrid1,The_J);
  else
    The_J:=The_J+1;  // смещать курсор нужно только если не было сдвига элементов удалением.
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает)))

Comment: с конца просто надо двигаться при удалении

Comment: @teran не всегда, но в случае автора проще сжимать таблицу по факту после удаления всех элементов, а не после удаления единичного элемента, что даст большой прирост скорости... :)

Comment: кардинальный прирост скорости тут даст `disableControls()`, или как там его, запамятовал уже.

Comment: еще там вроде пишут что удаление строки есть в protected методе родителя, который можно дернуть через хэлпер, а не эти циклы гонять, ну или одинарный цикле с assign строки, а не кажую ячейку переписывать

Comment: @teran На самом деле там можно играть с адресами памяти строк, и ничего никуда не копировать, а переписать ссылки, но это не тот уровень который доступен автору вопроса, поэтому даже близко таких советов не давал, самое простое: сжатие после удаления, и правильное удаление(отключение цикла отрисовки на момент изменения кол-ва очень поднимает производительность) :)